# Counting inside select knex js

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have two sets of tables which look as follows

**User table**

```
|  id| name |
|----|------|
|  1 |  x   |
|  2 |  y   |
|  3 |  z   |
```

**Visits table**

```
| event_id | user_id |
|----------|---------|
|     1    |  1      |
|     2    |  2      |
|     3    |  3      |
|     4    |  1      |
|     5    |  1      |
|     1    |  2      |
```

How do i get the number of visits by each user along with the name of the user. 
I know raw SQL can be used with knex and I can easily do this with a SQL query. I curious to know if this is possible using only knex js.

```
await knex('visits').count().groupBy('user_id');
```

The above query would give me the count of visits by each user. How do i get the name of the user in the same query.

I am looking for an output which looks like below

```
| user_id  | name | count |
|----------|------|-------|
|     1    |  x   |   3   |
|     2    |  y   |   2   |
|     3    |  z   |   1   |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```js
knex('visits')
  .select(['visits.user_id AS user_id', 'user.name'])
  .count('visits.user_id AS count')
  .leftJoin('user', 'user.id', 'visits.user_id')
  .groupBy(['visits.user_id', 'user.name']);
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the `raw` call, note that you can do `knex.select([...]).count('visits.user_id AS count')`.

Comment: how would you do a count where a where clause? could all `users` where `active is true` for example?

Comment: @TimBogdanov you have to add `.where('user.active',true)` before you do the `groupby`